# Laravel Get previous records by date (optimization)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, eager-loading

I have a bookings table with fields:

- name | String
- from | Datetime
- to | Datetime

I select some of those bookings and display them as a list. I also check if the previous booking is less than 30 days apart.

I do this by querying for each booking the previous booking:

```
@if ($booking->previousBooking()) // Simplified version but you get the idea
```

The underlying code:

```
public function previousBooking()
    {
        return Booking::where('from', '<', $this->from)
            ->orderByDesc('from')
            ->first();
    }
```

You might have guessed it already: it adds a query for each booking.

The best scenario would be to kind of eager load the "previous booking" (with) so that it is accessible like:

```
$booking->previous_booking->from
```

Is there any possible way to do it like this?

Constraints:

- I can't query all bookings, order them by "from" and then just get the previous index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](https://reinink.ca/articles/dynamic-relationships-in-laravel-using-subqueries) by Jonathan Reinink. You can apply his solution by simulating a `previous_booking_id` on your Booking model. Then add the `previousBooking()` relationship and query that using `with('previousBooking')`. Let me know if you need any help on the implementation.

#### Update

---

Add the following scope to your Booking model:

```
public function previousBooking()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Booking::class);
}

public function scopeWithPreviousBooking($query)
{
    $query->addSelect(['previous_booking_id' => Booking::select('id')
        ->whereColumn('previous_booking.from', '<', 'bookings.to')
        ->orderByDesc('from')
        ->take(1)
    ])->with('previousBooking');
}
```

You can now get all your bookings with their previous booking id included using this:

```
$bookings = Booking::withPreviousBooking()->get();
```

All bookings should now have a `previous_booking_id`. We add the `with('previousBooking')` to the end of the scope as if we query a relation of the booking. Eloquent does not care whether that `previous_booking_id` is in the database or not, as long as it's available in the model (which we've done by the `addSelect()` method).

You should now be able to use your requested solution in your view:

```
$booking->previousBooking->from
```

**Note: you can only access the previousBooking relation if you've applied the scope. If not, the `previous_booking_id` is not available, and the relation will therefore be null. If you always want to load the previous booking, consider to add it as a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes). However, I recommend to just apply the scope where it's needed.**

Comment: How would you simulate previous_booking_id?

Comment: I've updated my answer. This should work nicely for you! It's the most optimized solution I know of.

Comment: Ok I got that far (added return $this->belongsTo(Booking::class, 'previous_booking_id');). But now I get for each booking the same previousbooking(the same ID). Do you know where that could come from?

Comment: The problem is in the subquery. Is 'from' a date? Can you make sure the records don't all have the same from? Try to rewrite the subquery to make sure that's selecting the right previous booking

Comment: Yup found it. I needed to change the table name like this:  DB::table('Bookings AS previous_booking')->select('previous_booking.id')

Comment: Yes it works. Could you also update your code to use: ->whereColumn('previous_booking.from', '<', 'bookings.to') instead of where('from', '<', $this->from) for the next guy to run into the same problem. Thanks a lot!